# Identify "ZL5P" IC in laser driver

Tags: identification, boost, laser-driver

I would like to find a datasheet for a part labelled "**ZL5P**", found on a small PCB inside a very cheap laser pointer.

[image]

- (large solder blob on left is 3V input, blob on right is GND, laser
  diode is black plastic package on extreme left).

The part measures as a standard "SOT23-6" package and I believe it is a voltage boosting IC of some sort.  It is accompanied by an inductor (adjacent) and a couple of SMD caps (on the other side of the PCB).

The circuit power input is a pair of AAA cells (e.g. 3v).  The output seems to be 5.4V going into one pin of a 3 pin laser diode (405nm purple laser diode).

The circuit draws 0.17 Amps from the cells.

I found one hit on alibaba for this part (37 cents each) but it made no mention of the full part number, nor the manufacturer.

Comment: 10 second Google search: http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/212243/KINGBOR/KB4317.html

Comment: I wasn't so fortunate in my searching as you.  The pages I saw bore no mention of KB4317.  But thank you anyway.

Comment: +1 for clear picture. Identification of bootleg ICs was always a problem for me as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to show you how I came across the link, here's what I did. It could prove useful in the future to know how to refine keyword searches to find what you want for any generic IC, etc.

Searched Google for "zl5p SOT23," first result was "Aliexpress.com : Buy 20pcs KB4317 ZL54/ZL5P SOT23 6 from ..." This result has some extra information, namely the string "KB4317."

As such, I started a second refined search for "KB4317 zl5p SOT23," which led to the first result being the link I posted in my comment from alldatasheet that shows the details to be a Kingbor constant-current LED driver IC: http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/212243/KINGBOR/KB4317.html

Comment: +1 Good description of your search procedure. It would be better if the datasheet actually showed the marking the OP has rather than a different one. As it is we have only the dubious Aliexpress listing to indicate that ZL54 is the same (or similar to?) ZL5P. If it was something important that wouldn't be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's a boost regulator Ic from a little known Taiwanese supplier with factory in China.  looks good.

http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/212243/KINGBOR/KB4317/+Q13_55VHhMhDRu+OHCCvh+/datasheet.pdf

KB (Kingbor) brand was established in Taiwan in 1998, the company focused on the power IC design and development of high-tech enterprises, in order to facilitate the support of domestic customers, in 2004 in Shenzhen, the establishment of kingbor Shenzhen company. The company has a very competitive product market, and give customers a complete solution to meet the needs of all types of customers. DC-DC converter, DC-DC step-down converter, DC-DC step-up converter, synchronous buck DC-DC converter, synchronous step-up DC-DC converter, synchronous boost DC-DC converter, Low dropout (LDO) regulator, lithium battery charge management IC, LED driver IC, backlight driver, voltage detection IC, charge pump, MOS tube. Product applications are very broad, all kinds of digital products, portable electronic products, such as: learning machine, point of time T, tablet PCs, mobile power, industrial equipment

It could be a patent infringement on TI's 2002 design
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61041.pdf